# C# equivalent to Objective-C's addSubview

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

Does C# (WinForms) support adding a view or control to another control? Could anyone give me an example? Thanks in advance.

I use this code in Objective-C.

```
[aView addSubview:anotherView];
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? What sort of app are you building (WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, etc)?

Comment: What's the definition of view in ObjC/Cocoa land?

Comment: @frou "In Cocoa, a view is a rectangular section of the screen contained in a window. It is responsible for handling all drawing and user-initiated events within its frame. Cocoa provides the NSView class as an abstract view implementation that subclasses use as the basis for implementing custom display and user interaction." I think it's equivalent to a control in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this programatically with a Panel.

You could also use Visual Studio's Designer GUI to create a UserControl, which is more reusable, since you will be able to drag and drop it on to any form at design time.

Sorry if I misunderstand the question.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Panel p = new Panel()
    {
        BackColor = Color.PowderBlue,
        Location = new Point(10, 10)
    };

    p.Controls.Add(new Label()
        {
            Text = "Hello",
            BackColor = Color.PaleGreen,
            Location = new Point(20, 20)
        });

    p.Controls.Add(new Button()
        {
            Text = "Woof",
            BackColor = Color.Orchid,
            Location = new Point(60, 60)
        });

    this.Controls.Add(p);
}
```

[alt text http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/5861/captureek.png](http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/5861/captureek.png)

Comment: Image link is broken.